# Traceback Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pycharm, anaconda

How to install tensor-keras using conda? I have below error message. I see this error while importing below module
Here i copied a snipped of my code what i am actually trying in my code

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import tensorflow as tf

callback=tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath='Regressor_model.h5',
                                                monitor='mean_absolute_error',
                                                verbose=0,
                                                save_best_only=True,
                                                save_weights_only=False,
                                                mode='auto')
```

I was successfully installed tensorflow in Anaconda prompt by using below commands.

conda create -n tf tensorflow
conda activate tf
conda install keras

By the way i restarted pycharm IDE a couple a times. I still have same error

conda create -n tf tensorflow
conda activate tf
conda install keras

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rethi1\Anaconda-python\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3418, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-353837d93f8d>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/rethi1/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/stock_prediction_test/__init__.py', wdir='C:/Users/rethi1/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/stock_prediction_test')
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.2.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.2.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/rethi1/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/stock_prediction_test/__init__.py", line 273, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.2.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'
```

I tried a simple code which imports and uses tensorflow module

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Initialize two constants
x1 = tf.constant([9,10,11,12])
x2 = tf.constant([5,6,7,8])

# Multiply
result = tf.multiply(x1, x2)

# Print the result
print(result)
```

Error looks similar to above unable to use the module

```
x1 = tf.constant([9,10,11,12])
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'constant'
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you actually import tensorflow? Because if that does not work, no module under tensorflow will work anyway

Comment: Good point. I updated a piece a code above again which i have tried after reading your comment. I am using Python 3.7.9
I knew tensorflow is supported upto python 3.8.0 
Please correct me if i am wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you do not have a script named tensorflow.py inside your own custom code/scripts.

Comment: I have it many places: For example see below
\Anaconda-python\Lib\site-packages\opt_einsum\backends\tensorflow.py  
\Anaconda-python\envs\tf\Lib\site-packages\opt_einsum\backends
Should i delete this and try executing again?

Comment: No, I  said inside your own custom code/scripts, not in installed packages.

Comment: No, I do not have tensorflow.py at any other location except in my installed packages

Comment: then do this after importing tensorflow, print(tensorflow), and report back the results

Comment: Thankyou very much for replying back everytime. I figured out a soultion which is working now. I downgraded my py version to python 3.6.8
Recommended to follow: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-install 
Reasone for the issue is very obvious. Most of the users might experience the same problem. Usage of non compatable version which are completely out of bound.