# No module named 'tensorflow.keras' ModuleNotFoundError:

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, modulenotfounderror

My system information :

```
Windows version :  11
Python version  :  3.10.7
Tensorflow      :  2.11.0
pip             :  22.3.1
```

I have checked the previous questions which are similar to mine but they didn't help.

- [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59231793/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-tensorflow-keras)
- [Traceback Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64684702/traceback-error-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-tensorflow-keras)

I prefer to use **virtual env** over **Conda** thats why I am not using tensorflow through Conda.

When I run the below program in Jupyter lab its giving error.

```
import sys
sys.version
```

> '3.10.7 (tags/v3.10.7:6cc6b13, Sep  5 2022, 14:08:36) [MSC v.1933 64
> bit (AMD64)]'

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
```

> ---
>
> ```
> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
> Input In [2], in <cell line: 5>()
>       3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>       4 import tensorflow as tf
> ----> 5 import tensorflow.keras as keras
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'
> ```

How to fix **ModuleNotFoundError**: No module named 'tensorflow.keras' ?

Comment: If you comment out the Keras line and instead check the version of tensorflow, what do you get? Is it what you expect?

Comment: How to check tensorflow version?

Comment: Try printing out tf.__version__

Comment: Executing `tf.__version__` gives `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '__version__'`

Comment: I suggest googling these problems until you can print out that version and verify it's correct

Comment: `pip freeze` gives tensorflow version is tensorflow==2.11.0

Comment: This error sounds like the tensorflow you're using at runtime might be different than the one you see at your command line. I could be wrong, so knowing that version from inside Python is useful to rule out this source of the issue

Comment: `pip show tensorflow`  statement  in the **Jupyter notebook** displayed the tensorflow `Version: 2.11.0`

Comment: I don't have any directory named tensorflow

Comment: after importing tensorflow, do print(tensorflow) and report the result here.

Comment: <module 'tensorflow' (<_frozen_importlib_external._NamespaceLoader object at 0x00000188B312AD40>)>

Comment: I think your tensorflow installation is somehow incomplete or corrupted, because the print should show something like: <module 'tensorflow' from '/home/<user>/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py'> or similar path.

Comment: Actually, when you import tensorflow, do you get errors or strange messages?

Comment: No while importing tensorflow into my project doesn't give any **error**. @Dr Snoppy I think you are correct `the tensorflow installation is somehow incomplete or corrupted`. I uninstalled the current latest version of tensorflow and installed previous version of it and this has fixed the issue. Now when I `print(tensorflow)` it is  displaying the path of tensorflow and I can also `import tensorflow.keras`.

Answer (score 0):

Issue will resolve easily by doing the following steps

1. First you have to check whether you had installed tensorflow in system or not if yes then it will work in jupyter notebook.
2. But after installing in system tensorflow it shows this error same then uninstall python version and download 3.9 version and after that again install tensorflow  in cmd and install in system not in through virtual environment so jupyter note book  you can download and it will be work after importing tensorflow
3. Delete anaconda its useful but it is upto you so this was the simple steps you should follow and you'll see that the issue has resolved.

Hope, this will help you

Comment: Thanks @Krish for your answer but don't want to use older version of python as of now seems tensorflow doesn't full support `Python 3.11` buy it does support `Python 3.10`. I would like to use tensorflow on `Python3.10`.

Answer (score 0):

This means that to be able to use the Keras library, you will have to install TensorFlow first and when you import the Keras library
!pip install TensorFlow